# Cross-compiler error: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length host or target?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, icu

In order to cross-compile Qt5 on a Debian machine for RPi3 (Raspbian) I need to have ICU support. During configure it fails:

> ICU .................... no

the checking fails here:

```
checking for ICU... 
/home/mark/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -c -pipe -marm -mfpu=vfp -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6zk -mabi=aapcs-linux -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/mark/opt/sysroot -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -I../../../mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++ -o icu.o icu.cpp
/home/mark/opt/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/mark/opt/sysroot/opt/vc/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/mark/opt/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/mark/opt/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/mark/opt/sysroot -Wl,-O1 -o icu icu.o   --sysroot=/home/mark/opt/sysroot -licui18n -licuuc -licudata
/home/mark/opt/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicui18n.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Googling a bit leads to the missing of `lib32stdc++-4.8-dev` package. But I don't understand if the missing library is on the host machine or inside the sysroot environment.

I tried to search for unsolved dependencies:

```
objdump -p /home/mark/opt/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicui18n.so | grep NEEDED
NEEDED               libicuuc.so.52
NEEDED               libicudata.so.52
NEEDED               libdl.so.2
NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
NEEDED               libm.so.6
NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
NEEDED               libc.so.6
NEEDED               ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

all of them are in my sysroot directories.
How should I understand what is missing?

Comment: Looks more like the ICU you have in your path was compiled against a different version of libstdc++ or something like that.

Comment: Right: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/issues/41

Comment: This looks like the issue.